# store the <div> content in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

is there a way that I can somehow get the html content from the django template . I know that I can get the content of the input type by calling self.request.get("name") in get(post) method

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

but how about the other types like

```
<div>hello</div>
```

what if I want to store the html(hello) of the div into the datastore, is there a way to fetch it? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean literally the template as it was rendered on the server? There's two different things going on here: You render a template and send the resulting HTML to the client. Capturing that is easy. Then, the user fills out a form and sends it back. What precisely are you trying to capture?

Comment: Why would you want to capture elements of a template that *you* generated in the first place?

Comment: Say the client fills out a text filed in the template. **<input type="text" name="name">** and besides that there is a button that checks the content in the text field. **<input type="button" onclick="checkanswer()" value="Check Answer">**. However if i want to make self.request.get("name") works in order to store the text content into the datastore, I have to change the button type to **submit** like **<input type="submit" method="post" value="Check Answer">**,

Comment: but then the users will be redirected to the same page(say/check),which is totally blank,after clicking on the **submit** button,  if i dont fill out the get("post") method in the python file,( which byw I dont know why it is a blank page since they have the same URL and the previous one has content within it)  However, I want the users stay in the same page after they click on the button in order to fill out the new generated text fields...(assume there is a javascript to generate the fields.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can work with jquery ajax ,fetch from server data and then send data to server ...

read more about ajax + django : http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/

Answer (score 0):

HTML content exists on the client and is not sent to the server.

If you want to, you can send the HTML content to the server using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

In that way. You can use the jquery ajax form submit plugin. You can see some examples [Here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).